# Huge space between elements of Your Sites list on mobile app

Tags: bug, android-app, mobile-app

> [image: Stack Overflow on top, Latin Language below, and nothing in between.]

As you can see in the screenshot, there's a huge gap between sites in the Your Sites list in the app.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Swipe right from the left edge on the initial screen.
2. Tap the EDIT button.
3. Look at the list.

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S7 running the Stack Exchange app (version 1.0.89) on Android 7.0 (though this issue has been around for a while; I just forgot to report it :/). I don't own any other devices to test it on. The issue occurs every time I look at the list.

Comment: I blame your search skills ... and it shows my obsession with this site: I knew it was a duplicate at the moment I saw your screenshot ... and I don't even have an Android phone ...

Comment: @rene would you blame the Android app developers due to an inactivity for a long time?

Comment: @alexolut No, I would never blame hardworking professionals. Choices have to been made and given thee succes of the sites I assume they make thee right choices. That this has impact on further Development of certain features is a pitty but that is How It Goes